# Power Function using Loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, loops

I just started Python 2.7.
I am trying to make a program that executes power function (using loops) without using **import. math**
I think I got it except my program does not execute negative exponents.
The output only comes out as 1.
Here is what I have so far.

```
decimal=float(input('Enter the base number:'))
integer=int(input('Enter the exponent number:'))

def power_function(decimal, integer):
    num=1
    for function in range(integer):
        if integer>0:
            num=num*decimal
        if integer<0:
            num=1/(num*decimal)
    return num
print power_function(decimal, integer)
```

Comment: `range()` of a negative number is an empty list, hence never enters the loop.

Comment: ah! I see, then what can I do? Do I need to make it not enter the loop when is negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixing based on range of negative value.

```
def power_function(decimal, integer):
    num=1
    if integer>0:
        for function in range(integer):
            num=num*decimal
    if integer<0:
        num=1.0 # force floating point division
        for function in range(-integer):
            num=num/decimal
    return num
```

Comment: i tried your way but it still gives me an output of 1

Comment: Sorry, when I re-edited the post, I copied in your `num=1/(num*decimal)` expression instead of the correct `num=num/decimal` expression

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. Quick question though.. Why do I need to put "num=1" as a global term? on line 2? I still can't grasp the idea of loops

Comment: It's not global - but it does need to be initialised outside of the loop because it is referenced in the right-hand-side of `num = num*decimal`. This would throw an error (`num` used before being defined) if it wasn't initialised outside of the loop.

Comment: I see. Thank you 'AChampion' I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I have made some adjustments

```
def power_function (decimal, integer):

    num = 1

    for function in range (abs(integer)):
        if integer > 0:
            num *=  decimal

        if integer < 0:
            num *= 1.0/decimal

        if integer == 0:
            num = 1

    return num
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix is to use `abs(integer)` for your `range`:

```
def power_function(decimal, integer):
    num = 1
    for function in range(abs(integer)):
        num = num*decimal if integer > 0 else num/decimal
    return num

power_function(2, 2)
# 4
power_function(2, -2)
# 0.25
```

Or just using reduce:

```
def power_function(decimal, integer):
    op = (lambda a, b: a*b) if integer > 0 else (lambda a, b: a/b)
    return reduce(op, [decimal]*abs(integer), 1)

power_function(3, 3)
# 27
```

Comment: I am only allowed to use loops and conditionals. I am not allowed to use anykinds of import

Comment: You can do it with anonymous functions too - no import.

Comment: How? do you mind showing me the source code? I am absolutely a beginner... even if you tell me what to do I can't comprehend it since I don't know lot of stuff.

Comment: Plus why do I need to put "num=1" as a global?

Comment: `num=1` isn't global - it's within the function and is just it's initial value.